# How to conditionally not load js for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

We have a situation where our contrib modules are being loaded for the anonymous user, but they are not needed. As a result, we are seeing higher page load times. We tried using `hook_js_alter` in a custom module with the code below. What is the proper way to not load the js files we don't need for the anonymous user?

```
mymodule_js_alter($javascript) {

  $javascript['somefile']['weight']=50;
  $javascript['somefile']['scope']=bottom; //region for bottom of the page

}
```

Current code:

```
function mymodule_js_alter(&$javascript) {

    if(user_is_anonymous()){ 
       unset($javascript['sites/all/modules/contrib/autocomplete/autocomplete.js']); 
     } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to load your JS in anonymous user, check the user if its logged in then load the JS file if its true. use [user_is_logged_in()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7.x) to check if user is logged in, place it inside your [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x).

Example:

```
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen');
  // This will load only in authenticated user.
  if(user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
*/
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
// Removes the js for anonymous users.
  if(user_is_anonymous()) {  
    unset($javascript['sites/all/theme/js/file.js']);
  }        
}
```

Comment: I tried using the code above (even after cache clear) and it did not work. For the anonymous user it was still loading the js file I wanted to exclude. What I did was I logged out and opened incognito mode, but still found the JS to be loaded for anonymous users. Are there any other steps I am missing?

Comment: Paste your code here, then will be able to tell you.

Comment: I have added it to the description.